# Devise issue while starting rails app in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a rails app on my server which runs perfectly when I do `rails s -b domain.name` but when I run `rails s -b domain.name -e production` or `RAILS_ENV=production rails s -b domain.name` I have this following error.

`=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in production on http://domain.name:3000
=> Run 'rails server -h' for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:244:in 'rescue in load_dependency': /home/deploy/appname/app/controllers/users/confirmations_controller.rb:2: unknown regexp options - cfrat (SyntaxError)
/home/deploy/appname/app/controllers/users/confirmations_controller.rb:7: unknown regexp options - cfrat
/home/deploy/appname/app/controllers/users/confirmations_controller.rb:12: unknown regexp options - cfrat
/home/deploy/appname/app/controllers/users/confirmations_controller.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected keyword_def, expecting ':'
  def show
     ^
/home/deploy/appname/app/controllers/users/confirmations_controller.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in 'load_dependency'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in 'require'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in 'require_or_load'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in 'depend_on'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in 'require_dependency'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in 'block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in 'each'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in 'block in eager_load!'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in 'each'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in 'eager_load!'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in 'eager_load!'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in 'each'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in 'block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in 'instance_exec'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in 'run'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in 'block in run_initializers'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in 'block in tsort_each'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in 'block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in 'each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in 'block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in 'each'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in 'call'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in 'each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in 'tsort_each'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in 'tsort_each'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in 'run_initializers'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in 'initialize!'
    from /home/deploy/appname/config/environment.rb:5:in '<top (required)>'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in 'require'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in 'block in require'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in 'load_dependency'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in 'require'
    from /home/deploy/appname/config.ru:3:in 'block in <main>'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in 'instance_eval'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in 'initialize'
    from /home/deploy/appname/config.ru:in 'new'
    from /home/deploy/appname/config.ru:in '<main>'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in 'eval'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in 'new_from_string'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in 'parse_file'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in 'build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in 'app'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in 'app'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in 'wrapped_app'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in 'start'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in 'start'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in 'block in server'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in 'tap'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in 'server'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in 'run_command!'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in '<top (required)>'
    from /home/deploy/appname/bin/rails:9:in 'require'
    from /home/deploy/appname/bin/rails:9:in '<top (required)>'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in 'load'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in 'call'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in 'call'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in 'run'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/bin/spring:49:in '<top (required)>'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in 'load'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in '<top (required)>'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
    from /home/deploy/appname/bin/spring:13:in '<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in 'load'
    from bin/rails:3:in '<main>'`

**Edit**

And this is the file causing the error :

`/home/deploy/appname/app/controllers/users/confirmations_controller.rb`

```
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  GET /resource/confirmation/new
  def new
    super
  end

  POST /resource/confirmation
  def create
    super
  end

  GET /resource/confirmation?confirmation_token=abcdef
  def show
    super
  end

  protected

  The path used after resending confirmation instructions.
  def after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
    super(resource_name)
  end

  The path used after confirmation.
  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    super(resource_name, resource)
  end
end
```

The error seems to come from Devise auto generated files but I cannot figure out why it happens only in prodcution mode.

Comment: Did you set devise's secret key in its initializer file?

Comment: Can you add the controller which is causing the error? `/home/deploy/appname/app/controllers/users/confirmations_controller`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you tried to override the devise default behaviour using `rails generate devise:controllers` and you may have changed them badly.

Please be sure that:

1. You need to override the default controllers, unless you can remove `controllers/users` folder (If the name of your model you applied Devise on is `Users`)
2. Check syntax in all the files in `controller/users`.